# Foreign Key Fields creating new objects instead of creating links

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an object with Foreign Keys, and it appears to be working when creating the object, but when I get the object from the database the keys appear to have incremented from the previous instance.

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def StartGame(request) :
    card = Card.objects.create(game_id = 1, cardType = 1, owner_id = 1)
    return JsonResponse({ "card": serializers.serialize('json', [card])})
```

For testing, I am just running this code. When I make a call to this view I get the following JSON Response.

```
  "card": "[{\"model\": \"Billionapp_App.card\", \"pk\": 150, \"fields\": {\"owner\": 1, \"game\": 1, \"cardType\": 1, \"trade\": null}}]"
```

However, if I query just that object now by going to its url I get the following response:

```
{
  "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/card/150/",
  "owner": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/150/",
  "game": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/150/",
  "cardType": 1,
  "trade": null
}
```

Where I am expecting the game and owner to be 1 (instead of 150). I have tried getting the game and owner and using those instead of game_id and owner_id as the following:

```
Card.objects.create(game = Game.objects.get(id = gameId), cardType = card.cardType, owner = Profile.objects.filter(id = profileId))
```

And had the same problem.

This is the model:

```
class Card(models.Model) :
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name = "cards", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name = "cards", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    cardType = models.IntegerField()
    trade = models.ForeignKey(Trade, blank=True, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

And the Serializer:

```
class CardSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer) :
    owner = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name = 'profile-detail', read_only=True)
    game = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name = 'game-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Definitely `Card.objects.create(game_id = 1, cardType = 1, owner_id = 1)` will create a object.

Comment: Correct, I am trying to create a Card object, but I am not trying to create new games or owners. The problem is is that instead of creating an object with relationships to the parsed game and owner, it is creating new games and new owners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `HyperlinkedIdentityField` you should use [`HyperlinkedRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield):

```
class CardSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer) :
    owner = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name = 'profile-detail', read_only=True)
    game = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name = 'game-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta :
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Yes! This was completely correct, thank you so much!